# Problems with jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm doing a redesign for a site and right now my goal is to replace an old way of opening a certain window with a new one (jQuery). This is how it looked before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGp5R.png and this is how it looks now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxSxx.png .Everything looks good, but there is a problem. The jQuery dialog works only for the first item in every page, If I press on another item, other than the first one, nothing happens. Also, If I continue opening the jQuery dialog it starts showing all the items in the page one by one (Example: I press on the first item and it opens the jQuery dialog with the contents of the first item, I press on the first item again but now it shows the contents of the second item and so on and so forth, it shows them one by one for some reason).

The php code:

```
        //                                     SHOP ITEM LARGE
    //This is how it worked before
//  print '<a href="';
//  print "javascript:regular('pages/item_large.php?shop=".$item->webshopMenu."&amp;nr=".$item->id."');";
//  print '"><img style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:0; padding-bottom:0px;" border="0" src="'.$img.'" alt="'.$item->Naam.'" '.$image_size.'></a>';
//  print '<br><small>Artikelnr. : '.$item->Artikelnr.'</small></div>'."\n";
    //This is how I'm trying to do it now
    print '<a id="save" href="';
    print '"><img style="margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:0; padding-bottom:0px;" border="0" src="'.$img.'" alt="'.$item->Naam.'" '.$image_size . "</a>";
    print '<br><small>Artikelnr. : ' . $item->Artikelnr . '</small></div>' . "\n";
    ?>
    <div style="display: none" id="dialog">
        <?php
        echo "<iframe src='pages/item_large.php?shop=" . $item->webshopMenu . "&amp;nr=" . $item->id . "'" . "width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0'></iframe>"
        ?>
    </div>
```

jQuery code:

```
    (function() {
        $('#save').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#dialog').dialog({
                modal: true,
                scrollable: false,
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false,
                width: 450,
                height: 445
            })
        })
    })();
```

Any ideas why this is happening ?

Comment: Can you show us what your PHP is rendering please?

Comment: Meaning your `print` statements are being used to print out mark-up, show us the mark-up/HTML please. Makes it easier to see what DOM you're working with. You can get to this by viewing the source, or inspecting the relevant elements.

Comment: @DeeMac Here you go (the code is spaghetti by the way, makes my work much harder): http://pastebin.com/cdygL6QT

Comment: You are loading all the pages in an iframe even if the user does not click the preview? That is a bad design choice.

Comment: @epascarello I'm not

Comment: Are you sure about that? I see an iframe being outputted to the page with the PHP code above. display:none does not prevent it from loading.

Comment: @epascarello Hm, any other way of doing that ?

Answer (score 1):

This is just because you can't make multiple HTML items with same `id` and expect this to work. Give them different `id`s or make this CSS classname-based.

For example you can make first element have `id="save1"` and first dialogue `id="dialog1"`

Class based solution would be: give the link `class="save"` and the dialog `class="dialog"` instead of `id`. Then the javaScript would be like:

Put the `<a>` and the dialog `div` in same section `<div class="section">` so they could have same parent element. Then:

```
(function() {
        $('a.save').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).parents(".section:first").find(".dialog").dialog({
                modal: true,
                scrollable: false,
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false,
                width: 450,
                height: 445
            })
        })
    })();
```

Comment: There is only one element with these ids.

Comment: Why then you say "The jQuery dialog works only for the first item in every page" ? If there's a loop - why we don't see it in your code?

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the problem of other items not opening the jQuery dialog. But now there is another problem. When I press on an item all the dialogs open for all the items at once

Comment: Updated, added `:first` to the selector.

Answer (score 0):

use classes instead of ids.  use a class for the save button like `class="saveBtn"` and a class for the dialog like `class="dialog"`. then wrap the save button and dialog in a container with a class like `class="section"`.  then you can use jquery's potential of finding elements relative to each other like this:

```
$('.saveBtn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dialog = $(this).closest('.section').find('.dialog'); // this will find the dialog that is in the same section as the save button you just clicked on.

    //then you do whatever else of the code you want here.
});
```

this solution allows you to code cleaner without trying to manage ids and random indexes to get the correct dialog.

Comment: Thank you, but it still opens all of them at once randomly

Comment: did you wrap each button and dialog in a container?

Comment: do you have a loop or something? cause that looks like its creating only 1 section

Comment: Code's not written by me so I don't really know, but I've checked the file and there are no loops concerning this problem, here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/H4VQQ08H

Comment: I changed  `$('.dialog').dialog({` with `$('.dialog:first').dialog({` and now only one dialog opens, but it's not the one i'm clicking on. It shows them randomly.

Comment: Do you have any ideas ?